# Connection between solution of similar Recursive Formula and Differential Equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, recursive-algorithms

### Main Question

I am looking for a reference, where a connection is made between solutions of recursive formulae and Ordinary Differential Equations (ODEs) which look similar. In my case the recursive formula is $x_{k+1}=a Q(x_k)$ and the ODE is $f'(x)=aQ(f(x))-f(x)$.

### Elaboration

Let $a < 1$ be some constant and $Q:(0,1]\rightarrow (0,1]$ be some smooth function satisfying $Q(x) < x$, in particular we use the example $Q(x)=x^2$. Let $(x_k)_k$ be a sequence defined by $x_0=1$ and the recursive formula :
$$
x_{k+1} = a \cdot Q(x_k),
$$
Furthermore we define the function:
$$
f'(x) = a Q(f(x)) - f(x), \qquad f(0)=a,
$$
I have found there to be quite a strong relation between the solution $(x_k)_k$ of the recursive formula and the solution of the ODE $f(x)$. In particular, both have the same fix-points. When one converges to zero, the other also converges to zero. In case of $Q(x)=x^2$, we have both the sequence and the function converging to zero and one can show that $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx \leq \sum_k x_k$, furthermore one can show that $\lim_{a\rightarrow 1} \frac{\int_0^\infty f(x)}{\sum_k x_k} = \frac{\log(2)}{2-1}$.

Comment: Is it $af(x)-f(x)$ or $aQ(f(x))-f(x)$?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but certainly there is a structural relationship between solutions for recursions and differential equations using linear algebra techniques.  In particular, the solutions are similar in that they are based on the eigenvectors and powers of the eigenvalues (or $e^{\lambda t}$ for ODEs) of the matrices that define the systems.  For example, $\mathbf{u}_{k+1}=A\mathbf{u}_{k}$ with matrix $A$ is such a system, and similar can be constructed for ODE's.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @JohnB: It is $a Q(f(x)) - f(x)$, corrected it in the question.

Comment: @ad2004 : I do think this is in the direction, but I only find theory for this for linear recurrence relations and linear ODEs?